# dataTables alert row/s with most of

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple table with the first column being 'Company' and 5 further Columns for 'Days' which is a Binary '1' or '0'

Using DataTables I am trying to get the Company / Companies names (Column 1) that have the most '1s' for the 5 days:

```
<table id="table" class="responstable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">Company</th>
  <th scope="col">Day 1</th>
  <th scope="col">Day 2</th>
  <th scope="col">Day 3</th>
  <th scope="col">Day 4</th>
  <th scope="col">Day 5</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Company1</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company2</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company3</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company4</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Company5</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
  <td align="center">1</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
  <td align="center">0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<input id="btnSubmit" type='button' value='Alert Rows'>
```

I will include my javascript which at the moment is just counting the total rows so not that much help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

        var table = $('#table').DataTable();

        var rowCount = table.rows()[0].length;

        for (var row=0;row<rowCount;row++) {

            //Not sure what to do here

        }
        alert(rowCount); //I need this to be company / companies name from 1st column.
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data().  You access the individual row data to check for 1 and 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want count the number of `1` in your rows, you can use [rows().every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) to iterate values.

To know the number of 1s for each row you can add the values, try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var table= $('#table').DataTable();

   $('#btnSubmit').click( function () {

       table.rows().every(function(){
         //Sum the values
         var count =  parseInt(this.data()[1]) + parseInt(this.data()[2]) + parseInt(this.data()[3]) + parseInt(this.data()[4]) + parseInt(this.data()[5]);
         //Get Company
         var company = this.data()[0];

         alert("The Company: " + company + " have " + count.toString() + " 1s" );
       });   

    });
});
```

**Result:** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/88/

Comment: How would this work for a table with hundreds of rows? Can we move the alert outside the loop and only alert the Rows with the highest count?

Comment: It's posible, which are exactly the highest values, you mean the maximum?

Comment: Lets say One Company had two '1s' Another had three '1s' and Another two had four '1s' I would only be interested in finding the companies with the highest number of '1s' so i would want to know the two Companies that had four '1s' only.